# tidyr::spread with X most frequent values (avoid memory issues)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Imagine that I have a column like column_1, but with 5 million rows.

```
column_1 
 x1
 x1    
 x2
 x3
 x4
 x5
```

I want to spread the column, into different new columns like this:

```
x1  x2  x3 x4 x5
1   0   0   0  0 
1   0   0   0  0 
0   1   0   0  0 
0   0   1   0  0 
0   0   0   1  0 
0   0   0   0  1
```

Therefore I used the spread function:

```
spread(data = df, key = column_1, value = column_1, fill = "0")
```

And that works. But, because I got very, very much unique values.. the result (in reality) is +700 columns.

**My question: How can I do this spread function, with the top 10 most frequent values?**

The other values, can be grouped in another column (let's say.. column_bin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
df = data.frame(column_1 = c("x1","x1","x2","x3","x3","x4"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df

#   column_1
# 1       x1
# 2       x1
# 3       x2
# 4       x3
# 5       x3
# 6       x4
```

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

# select top 2 values
df %>%
  count(column_1) %>%           # count values
  top_n(2, n) %>%               # select top 2 (you can use your own threshold)
  pull(column_1) -> top_values  # save top values as a vector

# group rest values and spread  
df %>%  
  mutate(column_1 = ifelse(column_1 %in% top_values, column_1, "xrest"),  # group together non-top values
         row_id = row_number(),          # flag row position
         value = 1) %>%                  # value to populate cells
  spread(column_1, value, fill=0) %>%    # spread dataset
  select(-row_id)                        # remove unnecessary column

#   x1 x3 xrest
# 1  1  0     0
# 2  1  0     0
# 3  0  0     1
# 4  0  1     0
# 5  0  1     0
# 6  0  0     1
```

Comment: You can use `top_n(2,n)` in place of the `arrange` and `slice` if you want to be more concise.

Comment: Thanks, it worked once, but when I rerun it I saw that the mutate function was not really working: 

Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Don't know why, but it worked when I assigned both code chunks to (e.g.) data1 <- df %>%...

data1 <- df %>%...

Comment: Do you mean that the process work for the example dataset, but not for the full dataset you have?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `tidyverse` solution, quite similar to AntoniosK's but using a `right_join` (coded as a `left_join` to preserve order):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  count(column_1) %>%
  top_n(2,n) %>%
  left_join(df,.) %>%
  mutate(column_1 = ifelse(!is.na(n),column_1,"other")) %>%
  rownames_to_column %>%
  spread(column_1,n,0) %>%
  map_df(compose(as.numeric,as.logical)) %>%
  select(-(1:2))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     x1    x3
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     1     0
3     0     0
4     0     1
5     0     1
6     0     0
```